# XamlServices.Save is generating an x:Name="__ReferenceID0" attribute while there is the RuntimeNameProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-4.0

I'm having troubles with XamlServices Serialization/Deserialisation.
I have this class :

```cs
[RuntimeNameProperty("Name")]
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {

    }

    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public int      Valeur  { get; set; }

    public Node Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return mChildren.Count > 0; }
    }

    public NodeList Children
    {
        get { return mChildren; }
        set { mChildren = value; }
    }

    NodeList mChildren = new NodeList();
}
```

NodeList is a short class defined as :

```cs
public class NodeList : IList<Node>
{
    // ... implemented using a List<Node> internally
}
```

If I create a node hierarchy, like this :

```cs
Node root = new Node() { Name = "A", Valeur = 2, Parent = null };
root.Children.Add( new Node() { Name = "A1", Valeur = 3, Parent = root } );
root.Children.Add( new Node() { Name = "A2", Valeur = 3, Parent = root } );
root.Children[0].Children.Add( new Node() { Name = "A21", Valeur = 5, Parent = root.Children[0] } );
```

and I serialize it this way :

```cs
using( TextWriter writer = File.CreateText( "test.xaml" ) )
{
    XamlServices.Save( writer, root );
}
```

Here is the resulting xaml :

```xml
<Node Parent="{x:Null}" x:Name="__ReferenceID1" Name="A" Valeur="2"
   xmlns="clr-namespace:TestCRTP;assembly=TestCRTP"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Node Parent="{x:Reference A}" x:Name="__ReferenceID0" Name="A1" Valeur="3">
        <Node Parent="{x:Reference A1}" Name="A21" Valeur="5">
            <NodeList />
        </Node>
    </Node>
    <Node Parent="{x:Reference A}" Name="A2" Valeur="3">
        <NodeList />
    </Node>
</Node>
```

As you can see, XamlServices is generating the "__ReferenceID0" attribute where it shouldn't doing this, since there's the RuntimeNameProperty attribute... Obviously, it's doing this because of the x:Reference (due to the Parent relationship), but the funniest thing is it's not even using the generated x:Name!! And of course, it gets worst when I try to deserialize it :

```cs
using( TextReader reader = File.OpenText( "test.xaml" ) )
{
    Node node = XamlServices.Load( reader ) as Node;
}
```

I've got the error "''Name' property has already been set on 'Node'", which is logical since there is, indeed, already a name ....

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two solutions, either you have to change Name property to something else like XName or anything that is not "Name".

Or you will have to turn off Parent serialization,

```
[DesignerSerializability(DesignerSerializability.Hidden)]
public Node Parent
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

But in this case, you will have to process your nodes and set the parents manually after the object graph was loaded.

Reason XAML does this is to serialize object graphs which are connected to each other instead of just a tree. And it uses Name to uniquely identify nodes, however it is their internal logic which will now allow you to use property Name when it is trying to resolve reference names.

Comment: I thought about turning off parent serialization, but I thought I missed something and there was an other solution...

Comment: Ooops, I hit "enter" too soon!

So, here's my whole answer :

I thought about turning off parent serialization, but I thought I missed something and there was an other solution... this one sounds a little bit hacky for me :)

I was convinced by this [website](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bursteg/archive/2009/05/18/xaml-in-net-4-0-serialization-and-deserialization-using-xamlservices.aspx) that using the RuntimeNameProperty was to allow me to indicate to XAML that the given property was the one that must be used to uniquely indentify nodes.

Comment: Anyway, I also tried to name the property to something else but it didn't work either. I guess I'll have to turn off the "Parent" property serialization. Thanks!